# Orden para renderizar campos

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap

Al momento muestra de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y requiero que me muestre el campo Hora a continuación del campo fecha:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto parte del código que estoy usando del .ejs:

```html
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <label for="fecha">Fecha</label>
                <input type="date" class="form-control" id="fecha" name="fecha" step="1" required>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <label for="hora">Hora</label>
                <input type="time" class="form-control" id="hora" name="hora" step="1" autocomplete=”on” autofocus=”autofocus” required>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row justify-content-center">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success text-secundary">Guardar</button>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Básicamente tu contenedor de los dos inputs no es flexible, estás usando el sistema de grid de Boostrap, sus columnas y rows, pero no estás cubriendo tus inputs de columna por una row, nada más necesitas agregarle la clase row a el div que es form-group, tu html quedaría así

```html
     <div class="form-group row">
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <label for="fecha">Fecha</label>
                <input type="date" class="form-control" id="fecha" name="fecha" step="1" required>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <label for="hora">Hora</label>
                <input type="time" class="form-control" id="hora" name="hora" step="1" autocomplete=”on” autofocus=”autofocus” required>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row justify-content-center">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success text-secundary">Guardar</button>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Gracias @Jorge Almada, funciono. Voy aprendiendo.